# How do I split a string into an array the length?

Tags: java, arrays

I'm fairly new to Java but I would like to split a string up into characters and store them in an array then calculate the total characters. This is my code so far.

public class Main{

```
public static void main(String []args){
String Example = "This is an example";      //String 
String[] array = Example.split(",");
int totalLength = array.length();
System.out.println(totalLength);

}
```

}

Comment: you don't need to convert it to char[] to find length, you could straight away use `stringInstance.length()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use [`String.toCharArray()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#toCharArray%28%29) and something like

```
String example = "This is an example";      //String 
char[] array = example.toCharArray();

int totalLength = array.length;
System.out.println(totalLength);
```

Answer (score 3):

You could do

```
char[] array = "This is an example".toCharArray();
```

Use the array `length` property to get the length